# SVN replace + revert loses file history?

Tags: svn, history, revert

If I do the following

```
> svnadmin create testrepo
> svn co file://$(pwd)/testrepo checkout
> cd checkout
> mkdir trunk
> echo something > trunk/myfile.txt
> svn add trunk
> svn commit -m "first commit"
> echo updated >> trunk/myfile.txt
> svn commit -m "second commit"
```

then naturally I get

```
> svn up
> svn log trunk/myfile.txt
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> r2 | user | 2015-01-27 00:45:59 +0100 (Di, 27 Jan 2015) | 1 line
>> 
>> second commit
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> r1 | user | 2015-01-27 00:45:59 +0100 (Di, 27 Jan 2015) | 1 line
>> 
>> first commit
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now let's say by accident I replace the trunk with an older version

```
> svn rm trunk
> svn cp trunk@1 trunk
> svn commit -m "replacing trunk"
> svn up
> svn log trunk/myfile.txt
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> r3 | user | 2015-01-27 00:45:59 +0100 (Di, 27 Jan 2015) | 1 line
>> 
>> replacing trunk
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> r1 | user | 2015-01-27 00:45:59 +0100 (Di, 27 Jan 2015) | 1 line
>> 
>> first commit
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And then I decide to revert this

```
> svn merge -c -3 .
> svn commit -m "reverted"
> svn up
> svn log trunk/myfile.txt
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> r4 | user | 2015-01-27 00:49:25 +0100 (Di, 27 Jan 2015) | 1 line
>> 
>> reverted
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> r3 | user | 2015-01-27 00:45:59 +0100 (Di, 27 Jan 2015) | 1 line
>> 
>> replacing trunk
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> r1 | user | 2015-01-27 00:45:59 +0100 (Di, 27 Jan 2015) | 1 line
>> 
>> first commit
>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So obviously even though I reverted the evil commit, my file history is now gone, I can't see any trace of the change in r2 anymore.

So first of all, why is this? Did I revert the commit in a wrong way?

Second, is there any way to restore the file history?

Thanks to anybody who can shed some light on this!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different peg revision when asking Subversion about the log. So, to see the history before the accidental delete, set the peg revision to one revision *before* the bad commit and you will see again your missing history.

In your example, try

```
svn log trunk@2
```

to see the missing commits. If you are not sure which revision exactly is the bad one, use the `-v` flag with the `log` command and check for any `A` lines, e.g. like so

```
svn log -v trunk
```

Comment: My goal would be to somehow restore the history again, though, so that no other developer needs to know about the bad commit.

It seems like I could have created a fix branch from exactly the revision before, merged the bad commit record only, the following commits normally, and then reintegrated the branch into trunk, or similar.

So what I would be interested in, would be a solution that makes the wrong commit as invisible as possible (in my opinion if no other commit followed the evil commit it should be possible to completely revert the evil commit, but I don't know how...)